# line too long error with columns

Tags: awk, command-line, sed, text-alignment, geany

I'm trying to align text vertically with a delimiter in Geany text editor:

```
idxMathExpress (MathArcCos _) = 120
idxMathExpress (MathArcSin _)   = 130
idxMathExpress (MathArcTan _)     = 140
```

I would like this block to be aligned like this

```
idxMathExpress (MathArcCos _)  = 120
idxMathExpress (MathArcSin _)  = 130
idxMathExpress (MathArcTan _)  = 140
```

I tried to pass the selected text to an external command :

```
column -t -s '='
```

to make the job.

But when I launch the command, I get the following message

```
column : line too long
```

and I don't understand why.

**Do you what is the problem whith this command ?**

**Do you know another way to align text with a separator with geany (awk, sed ...) ?**

Comment: Any chance there's an issue with line-endings? `awk`, for example, sees entire files as one long line when they have Mac instead of Unix line endings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`column` requires every line to end with a new-line, if the input ends without a new-line `column` will produce the `line too long` error observed.  To select the final new-line, with the 'Geany' editor, the selection must extend to the beginning of the *next* line.

---

Using `awk`, and its `printf`, to align text (as in your example).

```
awk -F' *=' '{printf"%s% 7s%s",$1,"="$2,RS}'
```